# OCamlをEmacsで書く

Tags: emacs, ocaml

OCaml初心者です。EmacsでOCamlのプログラムを書きたいですが、ocamlのemacsモードはどのように設定するのが良いでしょうか。

試しにpackage.elで次のように設定してみましたが、package-list-packages でみれる一覧にocamlはみつかりませんでした。

http://emacs-jp.github.io/packages/package-management/package-el.html

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives  '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(package-initialize)
```

環境は以下の通りです。
OS: Ubuntu 14.04, Emacs 24.3.1

Answer (score 1):

`tuareg-mode` が一般的によく使われていると思います。

参考: http://melpa.org/#/tuareg

Comment: ありがとうございます。ですが、tuareg-modeもlistから見つかりません。package.elは使われないのでしょうか？

Comment: @yozenam 自分の手元だと、 melpa でも marmalade でも表示されているので、package.el の設定がどこかおかしくて、初期化に失敗しているのではないかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntuとの事ですのでSynaptic等から`tuareg-mode`を入れるという手もあります。
（記憶が曖昧なのですが）自分のinit.elにはocamlに関する設定が見つからないので、そのまま使えるはずです。